# OBJLoader doesnt work anymore after revision 55

Tags: javascript, three.js

Im working with the objloader from the three.js library to render a cube in the browser. I had it working fine but after loading a new revision from git (revision 55) i cant get it right. The cube just doesnt show up in the browser. I also used the demo obj loader from git but no improvement (camera position is also alright). The objloader does not work for me anymore even tough it works for the demo model (male02.obj)...Did something change in the loader?

Comment: [whathaveyoutried.com](http://whathaveyoutried.com)? Post some example code or recreate your issue in a js fiddle for us to look at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a duplicate of https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/2949 As far as I know it will be fixed in r56. In the meantime if you find the OBJLoader from previous releases you can use that instead.